# operator<< overload resolution (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

The code below gives an error in the `a::b::print` function: `Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Foo')`.

The error goes away if I comment out the `operator<<` overload in namespace `b`. But I don't understand why that makes a difference because it has a different signature to the `operator<<` overload in namspace `a`. What's going on?!

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {};

namespace a {

  std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Foo &foo);
  void print(Foo& foo) {
    std::cout << foo;
  }

  namespace b {
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, double d); // uncomment to resolve error
    void print(Foo& foo) {
      std::cout << foo; // error here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As namespace `b` is nested inside namespace `a`, names declared in `b` will hide names declared in `a`.  When name lookup occurs in `a::b::print`, it searches `b`, and *if it doesn't find what it's looking for* continues searching in `a`.  So it does find operator<< in `b` and stops looking, and does not even consider the proper one in `a`.  When you comment it out, it doesn't find it in `b`, and continues searching into `a` and finds it.  You could fix this by adding this in namespace b:

```
using a::operator<<;
```

However, the *real* problem with your code is that you're not utilizing ADL (argument dependent lookup) properly.  Operators that work on user defined types should be in the *same namespace* as the types they operate on.  What ADL does is add extra namespaces to search, so that any arguments (or template parameters) involved with the call will have their namespace considered--automatically.  (This is why you can use the operators provided in the `std` namespace for builtin types when your code is outside `std`.)

So move `operator<<` out of namespace `a` and into the same (global) namespace where `Foo` is.  Or, probably better, move `Foo` into namespace `a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Chris. I still don't understand why name lookup stops after finding `operator<<` in `b`? `operator<<` in `b` doesn't have the correct signature needed for `std::cout << foo`, so shouldn't name lookup ignore it, and keep searching?

Comment: The order is: 1) find a scope containing the name, 2) build an overload set from all names found in (1), then 3) pick the best match, if one exists.  If it kept looking after a match, you could lose the ability to provide your own version of a function, and instead would only create ambiguities. Someone else could break your code too, for the same reason.  (But ADL is also maligned by library authors for kicking in when undesired, too, as it can silently change what you call in the presence of new functions added to other namespaces--if they are added and happen to be a better match.)